# How to define variable in function and use in class

Tags: php, variables

i want create new variable in class by function:

```
CLASS book{

   public function set($name){
      newvar($name);
   }
}

function newvar($str){
   ***????
   /// what is code for here***
}
```

Example:

```
$x = new BOOK();
$x->set('title');

$x->title = 'jack';
echo 'book title is: ' . $x->title;

echo '<br>-----------------------------<br>';

$x->set('writer');
$x->writer = 'tom';
echo 'book writer is: ' . $x->writer;
```

result:

```
book title is jack;
----------------------------------
book writer is tom;
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do it this way? And why you want to use a global function when you already have __get/__set/etc magic methods?

Answer (score 1):

it's php :)

```
CLASS book{
   public function set($name){
      $this->$name = null;
   }
}
```

or even with code below you can dynamically add property

```
$x = new book();
$x->writer = 'tom';
```

[demo](https://eval.in/559297)